# how to assign the value for global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I use the following script function for get the row `id` from the grid. It was working properly. I get the ID within the `click` function. But if I try to get the outside of the function it will display Empty. I need the click function value for `selr` outside? How to do this?

```
var selr='';           
$(document).ready(function(){
               $("#datagrid").click(function(e) {
                 row = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr');
                 getId= row.attr("id");//for getting row number
                 selr = $("#datagrid").getCell(getId,'companyid');//getting Row ID
                 alert('alert in'+selr);
                 });
                  alert('alert out'+selr);
});
```

Comment: selr will be assigned only on the trigger of click function. It will be empty for the rest of the cases. wat do you need exactly?

Comment: @InternalServerError i need to get the value for selr in outside of the click function

Comment: you can have the value only 1) if the click is called before and 2) if the getcell method returns proper value. check those two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, the value of `selr` gets declared only when you initiate the `click` function. So check after clicking the `jqGrid`.

The script inside the `$(document).ready();` will not work, and will show as empty because, after the document is ready, the `selr` wouldn't have set.

Instead of having a simple variable, assign `selr` as a global variable. Just replace `selr` with `window.selr`.

```
window.selr='';           
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datagrid").click(function(e) {
     row = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr');
     getId= row.attr("id");//for getting row number
     window.selr = $("#datagrid").getCell(getId,'companyid');//getting Row ID
     alert('alert in'+window.selr);
     });
     alert('alert out'+window.selr);
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't give `var`. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar if i declare like var window.selr=''; i get the Unexpected token  error

Comment: _"Instead of having a simple variable, assign `selr` as a global variable"_ - But `selr` is _already_ a global variable in the OP's code isn't it? (Unless all of the code shown is enclosed inside another function that isn't shown.)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar still i get the empty value

Comment: @user Do this. Remove that alert inside the `$(document).ready()` and assign it to something else. For eg, another function, and bind it to the click function of a link. Now initiate the `jqGrid` click function and then click the link. **It should work**!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the value inside a *click* handler, so it won't get set until the user actually *clicks*.

If you test `selr` and find it still equal to the value you initialise it to (`''`) you know the user hasn't yet clicked on the grid.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the second alert `alert('alert out'+selr);` **will** be called **before** the .click function has been executed. So, therefore the value of `selr` is not set.

If you find a way to circumvent this, you can further assure to access a global variable by using the `window` object. E.g.

```
window.selr = null
 ...
window.selr = your value
```

However, usually such global variables should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: The second alert will _definitely_ be called before the click function has been executed. Regarding use of `window.` to access global variables, why would that make any difference in this case when there's no local variable of the same name shadowing the global?

Comment: True, I have updated the answer. To use the `window` object can often be useful in being really sure to access a global ...

Answer (score 0):

you can not get selr value outside  click function , 
if **datagrid** is table id then  `$("#datagrid tr").eq(0)` will give you the first row

Comment: _"you can not get selr value outside click function"_ - Why not? It's a global variable. (It's just that at the point when the OP tries to use it in an `alert` it is still set to the empty string it was initialised to because no click event has happened yet.)

Answer (score 0):

*You are already assigning the variable as global.*

The problem is the variable is **initiated inside** a function which is triggered on click of `$("#datagrid")` and the `alert('alert out'+selr);` executes upon DOM Ready Event, most probably before the `click` event triggers.